# Inner Join along with left Join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, subquery

I have 4 tables as described below:

*auth_user_profiles* ( Table which contains user details )

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auth_user_profiles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `relationship` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-single 2-married 3-Engaged 4- Separated 5- Divorced 6-Other',
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phone_no` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `country` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `registeredip` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `registerdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `profileimage` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
  `gender` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `profession` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `aboutme` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `referral_balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `google_open_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yahoo_open_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;



INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` (`id`, `user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `birthdate`, `relationship`, `address`, `city`, `zipcode`, `phone_no`, `country`, `work`, `registeredip`, `registerdate`, `profileimage`, `gender`, `profession`, `aboutme`, `referral_balance`, `website`, `google_open_id`, `yahoo_open_id`, `facebook_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'dfdfa', 'ddfm', 638649000, 1, 'fghfllgdfg', 'kdddd', 9887888, '25896589518', 67, 'NNNooo', '127.0.0.1', 1393409056, 'cind.jpg', 1, '', 'sssssssppp', 34.03, NULL, 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlUhpWgJhYxjlgg8UjhsKR0u40IvYQrGZ0', 'https://me.yahoo.com/a/Yl_iKDxqkIJIvZ7y5KHTBdkNDw2L#79ed5', NULL),
(2, 2, 'Kichu', 'K', 0, 0, '', '', 0, '8958698565', 20, '', '127.0.0.1', 1394014161, 'default', 0, '', '', 0.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

*video* ( Table which stores video details )

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video` (
  `videoid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `videocode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `videotype` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '0-main or 1-trailer',
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `length` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `associatedvideo` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'trailer link',
  `videolink` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `videothumbnail` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `uploaderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dislikes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `permission` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '0-pending 1-approved 2-rejected',
  `genre` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_price` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `added_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`videoid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


INSERT INTO `video` (`videoid`, `videocode`, `title`, `videotype`, `category`, `length`, `associatedvideo`, `videolink`, `videothumbnail`, `uploaderid`, `description`, `views`, `likes`, `dislikes`, `permission`, `genre`, `language`, `keywords`, `ticket_price`, `added_on`) VALUES
(1, '', 'Video 1', 0, 0, 10, 0, 'teamwork.mp4', 'images (1).jpg', 1, 'The first video uploaded.', 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, 2, 'cartoon', '', '2014-04-28 12:16:31'),
(2, '', 'dddddd', 0, 0, 10, 0, 'video.mp4', 'images (6).jpg', 1, 'vc fdsdf sdfsdf dfgdf sdfd ghg.', 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 2, 'dfgfdg sd fsdf', '', '2014-04-28 12:46:17'),
(3, '', 'asdasfsd', 0, 0, 10, 5, 'video.mp4', 'images_(6).jpg', 1, 'dg', 282, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 'tdgfg', '11.2', '2014-04-28 12:54:17'),
(4, '', 'asedas sfgv', 0, 0, 66, 0, 'teamwork.mp4', 'images (8).jpg', 1, 'hdgh xdg fg dfgdf', 11, 0, 0, 1, 11, 2, 'video ', '', '2014-04-28 13:00:46'),
(5, '', 'sdfftgesgsdfgsd', 1, 0, 33, 3, 'test.mkv', 'images (2).jpg', 0, 'fgdfg', 242, 0, 0, 1, 5, 2, 'fdgdfg,video', '12.99', '2014-04-29 06:18:32');
```

*ticket* ( Table which stores ticket details for videos )

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_key` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `attempt` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `generated_on` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '0-new 1-expired',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;


INSERT INTO `ticket` (`id`, `user_id`, `video_id`, `ticket_key`, `attempt`, `generated_on`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 5, '0b9d4d5aee', 0, 1399262972, 0),
(2, 1, 5, '1f5de2cde3', 0, 1399263032, 0),
(3, 1, 5, 'ba2376bb21', 0, 1399263036, 0),
(4, 1, 2, 'd571360f37', 0, 1399267971, 0),
(5, 1, 5, '99d98364e4', 0, 1399276280, 0),
(6, 1, 5, '290486a5f5', 1, 1399281061, 0),
(7, 1, 5, 'cccc1c72ab', 1, 1399281148, 0);
```

*sendticket* ( Table which stores details when ticket is gifted to a friend)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sendticket` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticketid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sendby_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sendto_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `send_on` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;



INSERT INTO `sendticket` (`id`, `ticketid`, `sendby_id`, `sendto_id`, `send_on`) VALUES
(1, 2, 1, '10', 1399276280),
(2, 4, 2, 'sdasd@fjjgf.com', 1399276280);
```

What I need is to get the details of tickets which are gifted to me. I am using the following query but even if I don't have any tickets received, it is returning records.

```
$userid=1;

$query=$this->db->query("select s.send_on,s.sendby_id,t.ticket_key,t.video_id,a.first_name,a.last_name,v.title,v.videothumbnail from sendticket as s LEFT JOIN ticket as t ON s.ticketid=t.id 
        LEFT JOIN auth_user_profiles as a ON a.user_id=s.sendby_id LEFT JOIN video as v ON t.video_id=v.videoid and s.sendto_id=$userid order by s.send_on desc");
```

Here what I expect is to get the ticket details, video details for which the ticket was purchased and the details of user who have gifted me the ticket which is *sendby_id* in *sendticket* table. Currently I don't have any gifted tickets, so it should return null records. But instead it is now returning records which doesn't match with my requirement.

I know that left join won't work in this case. I tried with INNER JOIN along with LEFT JOIN. But it didn't worked. Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are your parameter values ? and if there are tickets for any user  what would be the expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering your records by using `ON()` clause (*and s.sendto_id=$userid*) this will filter records only for the table i.e is in right position it will not filter the whole result set,the result you are getting is due to you are using LEFT join,for your concern result set you need to use the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT 
  s.send_on,
  s.sendby_id,
  t.ticket_key,
  t.video_id,
  a.first_name,
  a.last_name,
  v.title,
  v.videothumbnail ,
  s.sendto_id
FROM
  sendticket AS s 
  LEFT JOIN ticket AS t 
    ON s.ticketid = t.id 
  LEFT JOIN auth_user_profiles AS a 
    ON a.user_id = s.sendby_id 
  LEFT JOIN video AS v 
    ON t.video_id = v.videoid 
    WHERE s.sendto_id = 1
ORDER BY s.send_on DESC
```

So if i check for `s.sendto_id = 1` there are not sent tickets for id 1 but if you want to test for existing tickets you can try using `s.sendto_id = 10`

> one thing is confusing regarding your table structure for sendticket ,i saw values in column sendto_id i.e(10 ,sdasd@fjjgf.com) you are saving emails and ids which i guess is not a good idea ,also if you are getting the user ids from request then i recommend you to use codeigniter's Active record library

**Edit from comments**

> I want to get the tickets which are purchased by me and not yet gifted
>   to any other and also those tickets that are gifted to me in a single
>   query

Below are the two ways but both solution uses `UNION`

### Solution 1 with NOT EXISTS

The first query is simply getting the tickets which are purchased by user whose id is 1 and no records from `sendticket` where `sendby_id` is from same user the query after union is giving those tickets which are gifted to this user

```
SELECT * FROM `ticket` t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM `sendticket` s 
    WHERE  s.`ticketid` = t.`id` 
    AND  s.`sendby_id` =1
)
AND  t.user_id =1
UNION 
SELECT t.* FROM `ticket` t 
JOIN sendticket s ON(s.`ticketid` = t.`id`)
WHERE s.`sendto_id` =1
```

### Solution 2 using joins only

```
SELECT t.* FROM `ticket` t 
LEFT JOIN sendticket s ON(s.`ticketid` = t.`id` AND s.`sendby_id` =1)
WHERE s.`sendby_id` IS NULL AND  t.user_id =1
UNION 
SELECT t.* FROM `ticket` t 
JOIN sendticket s ON(s.`ticketid` = t.`id`)
WHERE s.`sendto_id` =1
```

Comment: I am sending ticket to users in 2 cases, either we can choose from our friends list or can enter email address (for those who are not yet registered). In that case I'm saving email address.

Comment: @Jenz Yes,what is it ?

Comment: I want to get the tickets which are purchased by me and not yet gifted to any other and also those tickets that are gifted to me in a single query.

Comment: @Jenz see my updated answer hope it works well if i understand you correctly

Comment: I also need video details corresponding to the ticket.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52090/discussion-between-m-khalid-junaid-and-jenz)